# Sufficient statistics of $p_{\theta}(x) = (2\theta)^{-1}e^{-|x|/\theta}$

Tags: statistics, sufficient-statistics

Suppose $x_1 \cdots x_n$ are iid sample from the double-exponential distribution with density: $$p_{\theta}(x) = (2\theta)^{-1}e^{-|x|/\theta}$$ It is obvious from the factorization theorem that $t(x) = \sum_i|x_i|$ is sufficient. How do I find the conditional distribution of the data given $T = t$?

I had thought of finding the gamma density that equates to the exponential distribution:

$$T = \frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}(t^{\alpha-1}e^{-|t|\beta})$$

Such that $\beta = \theta^{-1}$ and $\alpha=1$

$$\implies T = \theta^{-1}(e^{-|t|\theta^{-1}})$$

$$P(X_1=x_1 \cdots, X_n = x_n | T=t) = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n(2\theta)^{-1}e^{-|x|/\theta}}{\theta^{-1}(e^{-|t|\theta^{-1}})}$$

However I cannot get $T=t$ free of $\theta$

Comment: Given $T=t$, the absolute values of the data will have a flat Dirichlet distribution scaled by $t$, and since the signs are arbitrary, for the distribution of the actual data you then in a sense have to divide by $2^n$. This does not give a probability as $P(X_1=x_1 \cdots, X_n = x_n | T=t) = 0$ when $n>1$.  Nor does it give a density in $\mathbb R^n$ as the distribution is restricted to a hypersurface.

Comment: @Henry I've had a look into Dirichlet distributions, and hypersurfaces however these seem to be way out of my current scope in statistics/mathematics, as well as those provided by the book.